# Error when deploying : ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type Exception

Tags: java, gradle, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to deploy a my spring boot application after upgrading version to 2.7.8. Since the version upgrade I am not able to deploy my application though I can build it successfully. The application employs Kafka, but I do not know if this is what is causing the problem. Below is the error message I am receiving:

```
2023-02-17 12:49:53,527 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper.builder(JsonMapper.java:114)
        at org.springframework.kafka.support.JacksonUtils.enhancedObjectMapper(JacksonUtils.java:58)
        at org.springframework.kafka.support.JacksonUtils.enhancedObjectMapper(JacksonUtils.java:47)
        at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.<init>(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:112)
        at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.<init>(MessagingMessageConverter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:65)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListenerInstance(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:205)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListener(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:161)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupMessageListener(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:501)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:486)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:369)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:68)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.createListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:208)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:179)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:152)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.registerAllEndpoints(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:196)
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:186)
        at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:279)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:974)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
        at com.ocoe.edd.service.App.main(App.java:28)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```

I have tried excluding the com.fasterxml.jackson dependencies all together just to see if that would allow the app to deploy, but with no prevail. There are a number of dependencies that use com.fasterxml.jackson and I have read that this may cause problems. I have ensured there are no discrepancies in the version types, but still does not make a difference. Below is my build.gradle file with dependencies:

```
`plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.8'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'java-library'
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'


    group 'com.ocoe.edd'
    version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    def commonLibVersion = "1.0.0"

    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
        }
    }

    ext {
        set('springBootAdminVersion', "2.7.4")
        set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.5")
    }

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
     

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    implementation 'de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin'

    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server'

    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.7.0'
           
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.0.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'

    implementation("org.json:json:20220924")
    implementation 'com.sparkpost:sparkpost-lib:0.27'
    implementation("com.ocoe.flow.task:flow-task-common-lib:$commonLibVersion")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0")

    implementation("io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:5.5.0")
    implementation("io.confluent:monitoring-interceptors:5.5.0")
    implementation 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-spring:4.44.0'
    implementation 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-provider-mongo:4.44.0'
}
`
`dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-dependencies:${springBootAdminVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom:2.19.0'



`your text`
test{
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

App.class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class    )
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class App {

  @Value("${healthURL}")
  String healthURL;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public Docket swaggerConfiguration() {
    // return a prepared Docket instance
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/sparkpost/*"))
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.xxx.xxx.service"))
        .build()
        .apiInfo(apiInfo());
  }

  private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfo(
        "Email As A Service",
        "Health URL " + healthURL,
        "1.0",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        Collections.emptyList());
  }
}
```

KafkaConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@EnableScheduling
@Slf4j
public class EddKafkaConfiguration {

  private final EddKafkaProperties eddKafkaProperties;

  @Autowired KafkaConsumerRegistryService kafkaConsumerRegistryService;

  public EddKafkaConfiguration(EddKafkaProperties eddKafkaProperties) {
    this.eddKafkaProperties = eddKafkaProperties;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
    properties.put(SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getSecurity().getProtocol());
//    properties.put(KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY, eddKafkaProperties.getSchemaRegistryUrl());
    properties.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getGroupId());
    properties.put(CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getClientId());
    properties.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getAutoOffsetReset());
    properties.put(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getEnableAutoCommit());
    properties.put(AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getAutoCommitInterval());
    properties.put(MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getMaxPollRecords());
    properties.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(
        VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonDeserializer.class);
//    properties.put(
//            VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getSessionTimeoutInterval());
    properties.put(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getHeartBeatInterval());

    // Security configs
    properties.put(
        SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getSecurity().getTrustStoreLocation());
    properties.put(
        SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getSecurity().getTrustStorePassword());
    properties.put(SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, eddKafkaProperties.getSecurity().getSaslJaasConfig());
    properties.put(SASL_MECHANISM, eddKafkaProperties.getSecurity().getSaslMechanism());

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties);
  }

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(eddKafkaProperties.getConcurrency());
    return factory;
  }
```

Listener

```
 public SendEmailMessageReceiver(
      EddKafkaProperties eddKafkaProperties,
      MessagePublisher messagePublisher,
      EddEmailService eddEmailService,
      MongoDbService mongoDbService) {
    this.eddKafkaProperties = eddKafkaProperties;
    this.messagePublisher = messagePublisher;
    this.eddEmailService = eddEmailService;
    this.mongoDbService = mongoDbService;
  }

  @KafkaListener(
      topics = "${app.kafka.topics.send-email-topic}",
      concurrency = "${app.kafka.concurrency}",
      id = "kafk.xxx.xxx.consumer",
      idIsGroup = true)
  public void receive(
      Message<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> message,
      @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
      @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset)
      throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    //    log.info("-------------------------------------------------------");
    Date startDate = new Date();
    log.info(
        "Received Message is from Partition:: "
            + partition
            + " and offset::"
            + offset
            + " in thread::"
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    // log.info("Request Received From Kafka Send Email: " + message.getPayload());
    String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    JSONObject payloadJson = new JSONObject(message.getPayload());
    JSONObject payloadRequest =
        payloadJson.getJSONObject("body").getJSONObject("CAAS").getJSONObject("Request");

    JSONArray records = payloadRequest.getJSONArray("Records");
    List<JSONObject> updatedRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject currentRecord = records.getJSONObject(i);
      String docDetailsWithQuotes = currentRecord.getString("DocumentDetails");
      JSONObject docDetailsWithoutQuotesJson = new JSONObject(docDetailsWithQuotes);
      currentRecord.put("DocumentDetails", docDetailsWithoutQuotesJson);
      updatedRecords.add(currentRecord);
    }

    payloadRequest.put("Records", updatedRecords);

    ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
    obj.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

    String payloadRequestString = payloadRequest.toString();
    Request caasRequest = obj.readValue(payloadRequestString, Request.class);
  
    CaasResponse firstAcknowledgement = buildCaasResponseRequestLvl(caasRequest, requestId);
    
    messagePublisher.postEmailStatus(firstAcknowledgement);

    mongoDbService.createAndPostCaasEddStatus(caasRequest, requestId);

    List<CaasResponse> recordLevelAcknowledgementList =
        buildCaasResponseRecordLvl(caasRequest, requestId);
    for (CaasResponse secondAcknowledgement : recordLevelAcknowledgementList) {
      messagePublisher.postEmailStatus(secondAcknowledgement);
    }
    Date endDate = new Date();
    Long timeTaken = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    log.info(
        "-----------------------Done with DB persisting of NEW Processing Status message in :"
            + timeTaken
            + " milliseconds---------------------- ");
  }
```

Comment: Please show your App class and the Factories and listeners you've created for Kafka

Comment: Added what you requested @OneCricketeer

Comment: Given that you are getting an error from Jackson, Spring-kafka has its own json deserializer. You should therefore not be using the Confluent one

Comment: The same error is received even when I remove the confluent JSON serializer dependency and changed the way VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG is being Deserialized, from KafkaJsonDeserializer to a String deserializer. @OneCricketeer

Comment: See the javadoc for `VerifyError` - it implies there is some corruption in your copy of the jackson jar - I suggest clearing your gradle cache.

Comment: If you change to StringDeserializer, then your stacktrace should be very different, and not the same error, as the KafkaListener would no longer need Jackson. By the way, you should Autowire the ObjectMapper into your "Receiver" class constructor, not create a new one for every single Kafka event